# Transient behavior when power supply is plugged

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, mosfet, led

This is my first question in this amazing platform.

I just manufactured a board which has some LEDs controlled by an MCU via a MOSFET configuration (they have to be **initially off**).

I jut noticed that some LEDs are blinking **just when I plug** the board to the power supply. They are used to indicate UART traffic when UART is activated between the MCU ESP32 and the Xbee.

So I am wondering if someone could give me any hint, trick or known configuration in order to avoid this transient behavior?

This is the circuit I am using:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: pulldown resistors on gates?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you plug the device, XBEE_RX has a constant level ?

Comment: When I plug the device, Rx just blinks for a moment, then it remains off.

Answer (score 0):

When the Leds are controlled by the MCU through MOSFET you must take into consideration what is called "MOSFET self turn-on phenomenon" due to its internal gate to drain capacitance.

One way to prevent self turn-on is by adding an external gate to source capacitor but then it is better to apply the MCU output through a resistor to the MOSFET  gate.

The capacitor C4 must also be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the datasheet of your micro for the power-up state of the relevant pins. They will either be pull-up, pull-down, or high-impedance. They will stay in this state until your code gets a chance to run and configure the pins.

Then, design your circuit so that desired behavior occurs with the pin state at power up.

For example if the pin is initialized as pull-up and you don't want the LED to light up then you should use a circuit that lights it when the pin outputs a zero. However if you want it to light when the pin outputs a 1 (as would be the case with your RX) then that won't work. You could use a pulldown that is stronger than the pullup to force the pin to zero at power-up. You could switch on the supply to the LEDs in your code. Or, if the micro initializes is pins as pullup, you could use a NOR gate instead of a bunch of transistors, to allow the LEDs to turn on only when the micro sets a pin to zero.

This is not important for LEDs, so honestly, who cares. Where it really matters is stuff like actuators, digital control power supplies where you want it to power up at 0V and not max output voltage, etc.